# Why does my Angular.js controller executes its function twice in the following code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have an `ng-repeat` looping through an array of objects that belongs to `SomeController`:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController as aCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="category in aCtrl.categories">
    <p ng-show="aCtrl.checkShouldBeDisplayed(category)">{{category.name}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The controller is defined as:

```
app.controller('SomeController', function() {

this.categories = [{
  "name": "one",
}, {
  "name": "two",
}, {
  "name": "three",
}, {
  "name": "four",
}];

this.counter = 0;

this.checkShouldBeDisplayed = function(channel) {
  this.counter = this.counter + 1;
  console.log("executing checkShouldBeDisplayed " + this.counter);
  return true;
};

});
```

I would expect the `checkShouldBeDisplayed` function to count to 4 as there are four elements in the `SomeController.categories` array. Instead it counts to 8 - check it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/dyvM49kLLTGof9O92jGb (you'll need to look at the console in your browser to see the log). How can I get around this behaviour? Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

This is expected; The directive `ng-repeat` will repeat as many times as the framework feels is right; this is called dirty checking and you can read a bit more about it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs/9693933#9693933).

For this reason, it is better to think declaratively rather than imperatively. In other words, the method `checkShouldBeDisplayed` should only do what it says on the tin and not rely on the number of times it is called.  If you need to perform an aggregation or manipulation of some sort, that should be done elsewhere in the controller.

Comment: Right, that seems to complicate things. What I am trying to do here is override the normal `ng-show` behaviour, which is bound to the state of the model through some other state that is defined on the controller (imagine having `SomeController.firstUse = true` (instead of the counter), which is reset to `false` once the user interacts with the controller. Can you recommend an Angular way to do this?

Comment: If by interacts, you mean click or mouseovers, you can use `ng-click` or `ng-mouseover` and call a method which sets `firstUse` to `false`.  If interaction simply involves looking at it, you can instead do it in the `$scope.$on("$destroy"...` where you set it to `false`.  If that's not what you meant, please edit your question and add your overall goal. Then we can suggest different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

According to **[the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)**:

> The watchExpression is called on every call to $digest() and should return the value that will be watched. (Since $digest() reruns when it detects changes the watchExpression can execute multiple times per $digest() and should be idempotent.)
>   [...]
>   The watch listener may change the model, which may trigger other listeners to fire. This is achieved by rerunning the watchers until no changes are detected.

And all `ngShow` does is register a watcher:

```
scope.$watch(attr.ngShow, function ngShowWatchAction(value){
    $animate[toBoolean(value) ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass'](element, 'ng-hide');
});
```

Your function is `ngShow`'s watch-expression and is thus executed twice:
1. In the first $digest it detects the new values.
2. In the second $digest it verifies that nothing has changed and terminates.

---

In this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HF8BM1psvT0MxcaraUsn?p=preview)**, you can verify there are two $digest loops.

Comment: OK, thanks. Why are there two `$digest` loops here? Is that because of the dirty checking as @Mendhack is saying?

Comment: Yes, it's in my answer (look for `1.` and `2.`) :)